# removing WebKitFormBoundary from created file

Tags: java, rest

I have the following code:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/GEM-9639", produces = "text/plain", consumes="multipart/form-data")
public void convertCSVtoJO(HttpServletResponse response,
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream) {
    try{

byte[] file = BinaryDataHelper.readAvailableToBuffer(inputStream);   
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/CSVtmp.cvs");
fos.write(file);
fos.close();

//Create the CSVFormat object
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withHeader().withDelimiter(',');

//initialize the CSVParser object
CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(new FileReader("/tmp/CSVtmp.cvs"), format);
```

It creates the file but gives it a header which is throwing off my parser, is there anyway to strip this header and footer from the file>

Top of the file:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryCWCNJvEWAF8i1jgW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Cleaned-Inc-Town-County.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv
```

bottom:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryCWCNJvEWAF8i1jgW--
```

I'm passing the file via my rest client POSTMAN.

Comment: Are you using Jersey or are you using Spring? If Jersey was handling the request processing, Jersey should strip the boundary. This is not something you need to do yourself. Your `@RequestMapping` is not handled be Jersey, but you have a `@FormDataParam` Jersey annotation. You need to set some clear boundaries and figure out what framework you actually want to use, then use it correctly

Comment: Spring also has it's own multipart support, if you wan to stick with strictly spring, and it doesn't involve `@FormDataParam`.